# Very confused about Airflow Dags folder

Tags: airflow

I am very new to Airflow, I have set-up everything according to what are stated on their website. However I find it very confusing to figure out my dag folder location. **NOTE: I configure **airflow.cfg (/airflow/dags) within this folder has two files.**

```
/airflow/dags
---dag1.py
---dag2.py
```

But when I try to do **airflow list_dags**, it still shows the dags inside example_dags folder on

```
usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist_packages/airflow/example_dags
```

How can I see the path when I do airflow list_dags and to change it ? Any helps is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an airflow.cfg value under the `[core]` section called `load_examples` that you can set to false to exclude the example DAGs. I think that should clean up the output you’re seeing from `list_dags`.